# Content-Security-Policy Blocking Allowlisted Domains

Tags: google-chrome, security, iframe, http-headers, content-security-policy

I have been using a content-security-policy-report-only header for multiple weeks and have been seeing violations for multiple domains which are allowlisted in the same csp header. I placed all the domains I want to allowlist in the default src and don't have any other directives (other than style src for a nonce). I see other traffic which seem to pass and when I test the url on my own browser it succeeds without any violations. I have been looking at possible reasons behind this and that lead me to posts such as [Content-Security-Policy Blocking Whitelisted Domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66052239/content-security-policy-blocking-whitelisted-domains), [Why is script-src-elem not using values from script-src as a fallback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64322419), and https://csplite.com/csp277/

These links say that status code 0 or empty indicate the request was blocked while the browser tries to load the link and can happen due to ad blockers. I was also seeing these status code 0 violations reports and have filtered out status code 0/empty. But even after the change I still see a few requests that violate on allowlisted domains and with status code 200. Could this also be due to adblockers?

I did notice that some violations caused by extensions would list in source-file as chrome-extension so unsure if this could be due to extensions.  One thing I did notice was that if a report had a blocked uri that was not in the allow list in the default src, the violated directive would be a frame-src (which should default to default-src where there would be no domain so violation is expected). But in the case of a report with a blocked uri that was in the allow list, the violated directive and effective directive would be an img-src (which should also default to default but maybe it's not seeing the allowlisted domain there)

Example Report

```
{"linenumber":"",
"request":"",
"documenturi":"mysite.com",
"originalpolicy":"default-src 'self' mysite.com *.redirectsite.com redirectsite.com; style-src 'nonce-d93e18cc'; report-uri /csp-reports",
"violateddirective":"img-src",
"statuscode":"200",
"referrer":"",
"scriptsample":"",
"effectivedirective":"img-src",
"columnnumber":"",
"requestheaders":"",
"blockeduri":"https://x.redirectsite.com/s........",
"sourcefile":""}
```

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up switching from content-security-policy-report-only to content-security-policy header even though was seeing these status code 200 violations. After switching, still saw status code 0 violations but status code 200 disappeared. Perhaps it is a bug with how browsers support the content-security-policy-report-only header. But ended up working out for this usecase. Hope this helps someone else

Comment: Also have this issue. So many different browsers violate some resources which domain is in CSP allowed list.